# dataTask with NSURL instead of URL

Tags: ios, swift

I've been following an guide in the hope of learning how to use MYSQL with IOS apps.

However the guide is a little bit outdated, and I'm using swift 3 and I been editing the code to fix a few bugs. 
I have come down to a final problem, which is after I changed from using URL to NSURL, I can't use the "DataTask" anymore..

I have no idea how to replace this code of line.

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
   func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class HomeModel: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    //properties

    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

    let urlPath = "http://iosquiz.com/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.NSURLSessionConfiguration

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

    var jsonResult = NSArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: NSJSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let locations = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
        {

            location.name = name
            location.address = address
            location.latitude = latitude
            location.longitude = longitude

        }

        locations.addObject(location)

    }
```

Comment: As always don’t use `NS(Mutable)Array / -Dictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system. And `allowFragments` is pointless if the result is supposed to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

> I have come down to a final problem, which is after I changed from using URL to NSURL, I can't use the "DataTask" anymore..

Why did you switch from `URL` to `NSURL`? That's moving in the wrong direction. `URL` is the Swift bridge for `NSURL`. It should replace `NSURL` in all new code.

Switch back to `URL`. If you must use `NSURL`, you'll have to add an `as URL` when you use it in `dataTask(with:)`, since that method expects an `URL`.

---

There's a deeper problem here. You're using a configuration as though it were a session. Here's the code I believe you mean:

```
// vvv Changed NSURLSessionDataDelegate to URLSessionDataDelegate
class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol?  // <-- Avoid ! for this

    let urlPath = "http://iosquiz.com/service.php"

    func downloadItems() {

        let url = URL(string: urlPath)!    // <-- Changed NSURL to URL
        let defaultSession = URLSession.shared // <-- Use URLSession, not URLSessionConfiguration

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I switched to NSURL from a suggestion I read in another post. 
If I stay with URL I get: Use of undeclared type 'url'

Comment: `url` is not a type. `URL` is the type. Where do you see this "Use of undeclared type" error?

Comment: I found out it been working from the beginning, I think my xcode was acting strange after a recent update. I did a clean and it worked afterwards.